# Edit a file on CentOS 6.3 Minimal

Tags: linux, centos, configuration, command-line-interface, centos6

I installed CentOS 6.3 Minimal on VMWare Player, and I realized how 'minimal' the setup is...

Don't have network connectivity. From what I searched on google, I need to edit the file

> /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

but since I don't have any editor installed (as far as I know), I don't know how to edit the file.

How do I edit the file????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's virtually guaranteed that `vi` is installed, and maybe `pico`. Search Google for a `vi` tutorial.

Comment: sed is there, too.  pico is not on any CentOS 6.3 that I can see.  nano is on all but minimal.